# Wrong IP for Airport Express v1 - AirPlay in PulseAudio RAOP, Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, pulseaudio

Since upgrading from 17.10 to 18.04, I'm presented with AirPort outputs with a wrong IP address for my AirPort Express v1 which I'm using to stream over AirPlay.

Instead of showing the local address (192.168.1.2), I get some unreal 169.254.2.109 for reasons I can't understand, so - most obviously - audio won't be sent when selecting that, and streaming applications freeze.

PulseAudio and all necessary modules (pulseaudio-module-raop and pulseaudio-module-zeroconf in particular) are installed and defaulted. Maybe some Avahi/Zeroconf? I have no clue.

Any idea or help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was beating my head against the same issue for a while on Arch, and eventually found a solution via this thread:

https://github.com/hfujita/pulseaudio-raop2/issues/21

The solution was to run the command `sudo avahi-autoipd --force-bind wlp4s0`. You would have to replace `wlp4s0` with the name of the interface you are using to connect to the internet. For you it might be `wlan0` for wifi or `eth0` for ethernet; I expect you can figure out that part yourself.

Not being an IT expert, I gathered that the AirPort Express is putting out a link-local address (169.x instead of 192.x), and your computer can see it, but since your machine doesn't have a link-local address of its own it can't stream to the AirPort. The above command assigns your computer a link-local address.

If this doesn't work for you, there are a few other workarounds in that thread, but they appear to be more complex.

Comment: Brilliant! It worked straight away!
Thank you a lot for your answer, Stume! I was really tired of not being able to send music to the AirPort. Thank you again!